# why would this code crash with "attempt to access previously deallocated instance"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Aren't i doing this the standard way?  I see this format quite a bit and am not sure why my code eventually crashes and tells me I'm trying to access a previously deallocated instance.

Any help appreciated.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    vcListGrades *listGradesViewController = [[vcListGrades alloc] initWithNibName:@"vcListGrades" bundle:nil];

    listGradesViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    Course *sCourse = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [listGradesViewController setCourse: sCourse];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:listGradesViewController animated:YES];   

    [listGradesViewController release];

}
```

Comment: Is the course property of vcListGrades declared and defined as retain?

Comment: You write: "I see this format quite a bit" but that is not the way to decide how to write code.  Apple produces substantial and good documentation, also there many good sources that are fee or reasonably priced. Finally, one should never write a line of code one does not exactly why.

Comment: Yes, I'm defining the listGradesViewController's "Course" as follows:  @property (nonatomic, retain) Course                    * course;

Comment: Thanks, guys, that did the trick. Rather than declare "course" here before the call, I needed to declare it in my .h with a retain property and then synthesis in the .m.  I've changed my code from the above so that I simply refer to the 'course' variable at this point, rather than declaring it.   Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the problem is with your view controller, I would much likely say the problem is with sCourse, be sure of the memory management you do of the property course in your vcListGrades class. The management of the UIViewController seems to be just fine.

Comment: Thanks, 'El'.  is there any more i would need to do aside from this in the .h file?    I'm defining the listGradesViewController's "Course" as follows: @property (nonatomic, retain) Course * course;

Comment: Thanks, El, that did the trick. Rather than declare "course" here before the call, I needed to declare it in my .h with a retain property and then synthesis in the .m.  I've changed my code from the above so that I simply refer to the 'course' variable at this point, rather than declaring it.   Seems to be working now.

Comment: El !!!  It's back...  I have documented it much better now.  Do you think you could take another look?  Here is the new question...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706579/how-to-debug-func-name-controllerwillchangecontent-message-sent-to-de