# How to debug: *** -[<func_name> controllerWillChangeContent:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5909c60

Tags: iphone, memory-management, dealloc

Have I declared or used the "course" variable wrongly?  I need to send the user-selected course object over to the child UIViewController and am not having any luck.  This code works 2 times and then fails the third time through.

The runtime error I get is:

```
2011-10-09 17:04:41.403 [] *** -[vcListGrades controllerWillChangeContent:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5909c60
```

When I find that address using the debugger command: "info malloc-history 0x5909c60", it points me to the code that is presented below.

// Here is the offending code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:YES];   

    course  = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];  

    //create the new controller for next drill level into table
    vcListGrades *listGradesViewController = [[vcListGrades alloc] initWithNibName:@"vcListGrades" bundle:nil];
```

// ^^^ this line above is the line flagged by the error.

```
    // take the MO context with you to the next level of table drilling
    listGradesViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    // take the school_courseName record that was just clicked  with you as you drill into next table
    [listGradesViewController setCourse: course];

    // deselect the row that was just clicked - this according to mac style guide
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:YES];

    //push new controller onto stack and go for it
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:listGradesViewController animated:YES];

    [listGradesViewController release];

}
```

//Here's how course is defined in the .h file

```
@interface vcListCourses : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {

    NSFetchedResultsController *_fetchedResultsController;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    Schoolyear *_schoolyear;
    Course *course;

}

...elipse
@property (nonatomic, retain) Course *course;
```

//Synthesize line in .m file

```
@synthesize course;
```

and here is the info malloc-history stack

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x5909c60
Alloc: Block address: 0x05909c60 length: 176
Stack - pthread: 0xacff42c0 number of frames: 19
    0: 0x991e990b in malloc_zone_calloc
    1: 0x991ea837 in calloc
    2: 0x11322d4 in class_createInstance
    3: 0xefe5d8 in +[NSObject(NSObject) allocWithZone:]
    4: 0xefe3da in +[NSObject(NSObject) alloc]
    5: 0x83b6 in -[vcListCourses tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] at vcListCourses.m:428
    6: 0x36ab68 in -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:]
    7: 0x360b05 in -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:]
    8: 0x7279e in __NSFireDelayedPerform
    9: 0xfbb8c3 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
   10: 0xfbce74 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer
   11: 0xf192c9 in __CFRunLoopRun
   12: 0xf18840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
   13: 0xf18761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
   14: 0x19311c4 in GSEventRunModal
   15: 0x1931289 in GSEventRun
   16: 0x301c93 in UIApplicationMain
   17: 0x26e9 in main at main.m:14
   18: 0x2665 in start
```

Does this look right?

I define my nsfetchedResultsController like this in the rootviewcontroller.h file

```
The @interface RootViewController : UITableViewController  <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {

    NSFetchedResultsController *_fetchedResultsController;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton;
    Schoolyear *year;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
```

Here is the .m file for my NSFetchedResultsController

```
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;
```

Comment: How is the fetched results controller created?

Comment: What is course? Don't you need to do `[listGradesViewController setCourse: [course retain]];`

Comment: @ott - I tried the above line but no joy.  note the update - the offending line is actually the line below it where I alloc the new viewcontroller.

Comment: @PaulMason - Paul, see the edit to the original post above to see the definition of the nsfetchedresultscontroller.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm out of ideas, try adding a break point on the start of the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: follow the code with simple steps and see if that's what is breaking your code. BTW you have a double  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:YES]; Unless that is meant to be :P

Answer (score 0):

Please display the exception stack.  And you realize, of course, that when you assign "course", that's not getting retained.  To retain you need to assign to "self.course".

Comment: I had indicated originally that the offending line (428) was the "course" allocation line.  The offending line is actually the one below it.  here it is:     vcListGrades *listGradesViewController = [[vcListGrades alloc] initWithNibName:@"vcListGrades" bundle:nil];    // << this is the line flagged by the error.

Comment: I didn't ask which line was flagged by malloc-history, I asked for the exception stack.

Comment: Is that the same as the malloc-history stack?  I've added that in the original content above.

Comment: You got a runtime error.  Unless you're extraordinarily unlucky, immediately below that was the exception stack.

Comment: Got it, Daniel.  Thank you for the help.  I had failed to set the fetched controller to nil in the dealloc() routine several views down into the drill down.  Lucky to have found it - just stumbling through the code and tripped over it.   All good.  Thanks again.